# Digit reversal arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many three-digit odd numbers become bigger when their digits are reversed?
$$abc<cba$$ and $c$ is either 1,3,5,7,9. This is the furthest I managed to reach.

Comment: You must have $c>a$ and $b$ does not matter, right? Or more mathematically put: $$ 100a+10b+c < 100c+10b+a \iff 0<100(c-a)+10(b-b)+(a-c) $$ and whenever $a\neq c$ we have $100(c-a)$ as the dominant term so that we must have $c-a>0$ for $100(c-a)$ to be positive.

Comment: So I would say the answer is 20.

Comment: How did you work out the answer as 20?

Comment: Sorry, just like Hagen von Eitzen, I was too fast concluding that. The fact is that for $c=1,3,5,7$ and $9$ we have respectively $0,2,4,6$ and $8$ choices for it to be strictly less than $c$. Note here that $a$ cannot be zero since then the number $abc$ is not really 3-digit. This provides 20 choices for $a$, but I forgot that for each $a$ we can choose $b$ arbitrarily among $0,1,...,9$ so that makes the answer $20\cdot 10=200$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $abc<cba$ iff $a<c$. For each odd $c$, there are $c-1$ choices for $a\in\{1,\ldots,c-1\}$. This gives $0+2+4+6+8$ choices for $(a,c)$. The digit $b$ is arbitrary.